# How can you add a variable to a position in unity 2D?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I need help, I am coding an boss AI and I can't seem to add a variable to a position in unity.

Here is the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FistScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public float offset;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position.x = new Vector2(player.transform.position.x + offset, transform.position.y);
    }
}
```

When I use this I get this error:

> 'Assets\Scripts\FistScript.cs(18,9): error CS1612: Cannot modify the
> return value of 'Transform.position' because it is not a variable'

Please help if you can.

Comment: The [documentation for `Transform.Position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html) provides a code example that you can follow.

Comment: This question is not about [tag:unityscript]

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign Vector2 to float property. transform.position is a Vector2 struct with properties x and y. So you can't modify them because they are properties of a struct.  To modify the position you should create a new Vector2 object.

```
player.transform.position = new Vector2(player.transform.position.x + offset, player.transform.position.y);
```

Simpler variant:

```
player.transform.position += Vector2.right * offset;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to update position you can update transform.position, not the transform.position.x i.e

```
//update the position
    transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(horizontalInput * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime, verticalInput * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
```

For more information please refer to https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change only a single axis in `transfrom.position`, then you need to use a temp Vector2. Here is how to do it:

```
 Vector2 temp_pos=transform.position;
 temp_pos.x=player.transform.position.x + offset
 transform.position=temp_pos;
```

If You want to update the position directly, then you can just do this:

```
transform.position = new Vector2(player.transform.position.x + offset, transform.position.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access transform.position.x directly because it belongs to position's Vector3 struct. I encourage you to better understand [C# structs](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-struct)

```
 float x;
 float y;
 float z;

 void Move()
 {
   // THIS WORKS       
   transform.position = new Vector3(x,y,z);

   // THIS DOESN'T WORK
   transform.position = 23f;
   transform.position.x = 10f;
 }
```